# Python multiprocessing write to single gzip in parallel

Tags: compression, gzip, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to copy a large, compressed file (.gz) to another compressed file (.gz) using python. I will perform intermediate processing on the data that is not present in my code sample. I would *like* to be able to use multiprocessing with locks to write to the new gzip in parallel from multiple processes, but I get an invalid format error on the output gz file.

I assume that this is because a lock is not enough to support writing to a gzip in parallel. Since compressed data requires "knowledge" of the data that came before it in order to make correct entries into the archive I don't think that python can't handle this by default. I'd guess that each process maintains its own awareness of the gzip output and that this state diverges after the first write.

If I open the target file in the script without using gzip then this all works. I could also write to multiple gzips and merge them, but prefer to avoid that if possible.

Here is my source code:

```py
#python3.8
import gzip
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock

def reader(infile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, chunk_size):
    print("Reader Started.")
    while True:
        data_chunk = list(islice(infile, chunk_size))
        data_queue.put(data_chunk)
        coordinator_queue.put('CHUNK_READ')
        if not data_chunk:
            coordinator_queue.put('READ_DONE')
            #Process exit
            break
        
def writer(outfile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, write_lock, ID):
    print("Writer Started.")
    while True:
        queue_message = data_queue.get()
        if (queue_message == 'DONE'):
            outfile.flush() 
            coordinator_queue.put('WRITE_DONE')
            #Process exit
            break
        else:
            print("Writer",ID,"-","Write Lock:",write_lock)
            write_lock.acquire()
            print("Writer",ID,"-","Write Lock:",write_lock)
            for line in queue_message:
                print("Line write:",line)
                outfile.write(line)
            write_lock.release()
            print("Writer",ID,"-","Write Lock:",write_lock)

def coordinator(reader_procs, writer_procs, coordinator_queue, data_queue):
    print("Coordinator Started.")
    active_readers=reader_procs
    active_writers=writer_procs
    while True:
        queue_message = coordinator_queue.get()
        if queue_message=='READ_DONE':
            active_readers = active_readers-1
            if active_readers == 0:
                while not data_queue.qsize() == 0:
                    continue
                [data_queue.put('DONE') for x in range(writer_procs)]
        if queue_message=='WRITE_DONE':
            active_writers = active_writers-1
            if active_writers == 0:
                break

def main():
    reader_procs=1
    writer_procs=2
    chunk_size=1
    queue_size=96
    data_queue = Queue(queue_size)
    coordinator_queue=Queue()
    write_lock=Lock()
    infile_path='/directory/input_records.json.gz'
    infile = gzip.open(infile_path, 'rt')
    outfile_path='/directory/output_records.json.gz'
    outfile = gzip.open(outfile_path, 'wt')
    #Works when it is uncompressed
    #outfile=open(outfile_path, 'w')
    readers = [Process(target=reader, args=(infile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, chunk_size)) for x in range(reader_procs)]
    writers = [Process(target=writer, args=(outfile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, write_lock, x)) for x in range(writer_procs)]   
    coordinator_p = Process(target=coordinator, args=(reader_procs, writer_procs, coordinator_queue, data_queue))

    coordinator_p.start()
    for process in readers:
        process.start()
    for process in writers:
        process.start()
    for process in readers:
        process.join()
    for process in writers:
        process.join()
    coordinator_p.join()
    outfile.flush()
    outfile.close()

main()
```

**Notes about the code:**

- The "chunk size" determines the number of lines pulled from the input file

  - I have been using a much smaller test file while trying to make this work
- My input file is over 200gb when uncompressed
- My output file will be over 200gb when uncompressed
- This version of the code has been trimmed and may have some mistakes but it is based directly on what I am running.

  - All functional areas of the script have been retained.

I would guess that I need a library that can somehow coordinate the compressed writes between the different processes. Obviously this speaks to the use of a single process to perform the write (like the coordinator process) however that would likely introduce a bottleneck.

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016029/gzip-issue-with-multiprocessing-pool) related posts on stack but none that seem to specifically address what I am trying to do. I also see utilities like "[mgzip](https://pypi.org/project/mgzip/)", "[pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/)" and "[migz](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2019/02/migz-for-compression-and-decompression)" out there that can parallelize compression, but I don't believe they are applicable to this use case. mgzip didn't work in my testing (0 sized file), pigz appears to consume an entire file as input on the command line and migz is a java library, so I'm not sure how I could integrate it into python.

If it can't be done then so be it but any answer would be appreciated!

**-------**
***Update and working code:***

With help from Mark Adler I was able to create a multiprocessing script that compresses the data in parallel and has a single writer process to add it to the target gz file. With the throughput on a modern NVME drive this reduces the likelihood of becoming CPU bound by compression before becoming I/O bound.

The largest changes that needed to be made to make this code work are as follows:

- `gzip.compress(bytes(string, 'utf-8'),compresslevel=9)` was needed to compress an individual "block" or "stream:
- `file = open(outfile, 'wb')` was needed in order to open an unencoded binary output file that can become the target gzip.
- The `file.write()` action had to take place from a single process as it must be executed serially.

It is worth noting that this **does not** write to the file in parallel, but rather handles the compression in parallel. The compression is the heavy-lifting part of this process anyway.

Updated code (tested and works as-is):

```py
#python3.8
import gzip
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def reader(infile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, chunk_size):
    print("Reader Started.")
    while True:
        data_chunk = list(islice(infile, chunk_size))
        data_queue.put(data_chunk)
        coordinator_queue.put('CHUNK_READ')
        if not data_chunk:
            coordinator_queue.put('READ_DONE')
            #Process exit
            break

def compressor(data_queue, compressed_queue, coordinator_queue):
    print("Compressor Started.")
    while True:
        chunk = ''
        queue_message = data_queue.get()
        if (queue_message == 'DONE'):
            #Notify coordinator process of task completion      
            coordinator_queue.put('COMPRESS_DONE')
            #Process exit
            break
        else:
            for line in queue_message:
                #Assemble concatenated string from list
                chunk += line
            #Encode the string as binary so that it can be compressed
            #Setting gzip compression level to 9 (highest)
            compressed_chunk=gzip.compress(bytes(chunk,'utf-8'),compresslevel=9)            
            compressed_queue.put(compressed_chunk)

def writer(outfile, compressed_queue, coordinator_queue):
    print("Writer Started.")
    while True:
        queue_message = compressed_queue.get()
        if (queue_message == 'DONE'):
            #Notify coordinator process of task completion      
            coordinator_queue.put('WRITE_DONE')
            #Process exit
            break
        else:
            outfile.write(queue_message)

def coordinator(reader_procs, writer_procs, compressor_procs, coordinator_queue, data_queue, compressed_queue):
    print("Coordinator Started.")
    active_readers=reader_procs
    active_compressors=compressor_procs
    active_writers=writer_procs
    while True:
        queue_message = coordinator_queue.get()
        if queue_message=='READ_DONE':
            active_readers = active_readers-1
            if active_readers == 0:
                while not data_queue.qsize() == 0:
                    continue
                [data_queue.put('DONE') for x in range(compressor_procs)]
        if queue_message=='COMPRESS_DONE':
            active_compressors = active_compressors-1
            if active_compressors == 0:
                while not compressed_queue.qsize() == 0:
                    continue
                [compressed_queue.put('DONE') for x in range(writer_procs)]
        if queue_message=='WRITE_DONE':
            active_writers = active_writers-1
            if active_writers == 0:
                break

def main():
    reader_procs=1
    compressor_procs=2
    #writer_procs really needs to stay as 1 since writing must be done serially
    #This could probably be written out...
    writer_procs=1
    chunk_size=600
    queue_size=96
    data_queue = Queue(queue_size)
    compressed_queue=Queue(queue_size)
    coordinator_queue=Queue()
    infile_path='/directory/input_records.json.gz'
    infile = gzip.open(infile_path, 'rt')
    outfile_path='/directory/output_records.json.gz'
    outfile=open(outfile_path, 'wb')
    readers = [Process(target=reader, args=(infile, data_queue, coordinator_queue, chunk_size)) for x in range(reader_procs)]
    compressors = [Process(target=compressor, args=(data_queue, compressed_queue, coordinator_queue)) for x in range(compressor_procs)]
    writers = [Process(target=writer, args=(outfile, compressed_queue, coordinator_queue)) for x in range(writer_procs)]
    coordinator_p = Process(target=coordinator, args=(reader_procs, writer_procs, compressor_procs, coordinator_queue, data_queue, compressed_queue))
    coordinator_p.start()
    for process in readers:
        process.start()
    for process in compressors:
        process.start()     
    for process in writers:
        process.start()
    for process in compressors:
        process.join()
    for process in readers:
        process.join()
    for process in writers:
        process.join()
    coordinator_p.join()
    outfile.flush()
    outfile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite straightforward to do by writing complete gzip streams from each thread to a single output file. Yes, you will need one thread that does all the writing, with each compression thread taking turns writing *all* of its gzip stream, before another compression thread gets to write any. The compression threads can all do their compression in parallel, but the writing needs to be serialized.

The reason this works is that the gzip standard, [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952), says that a gzip files consists of a series of members, where each member is a gzip header, compressed data, and gzip trailer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I'm going to get CPU bound on the compression itself. Would be nice to be able to distribute that, but I understand the serialized nature of the data. Any clue how pigz manages to do it in parallel? And thanks for your insight :)

Comment: As I said in my answer, the compression _can_ be done in parallel. Each thread just accumulates its gzip stream in memory, and when it's done, it puts its data in a queue for the write thread to pick up.

Comment: Wow! I've done a little more digging and continue to come across your work and answers. [gzlog](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c) for example. I've only ever worked with compression at a high level... I'm looking at a [zlib tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/python-zlib-library-tutorial/) but don't understand the implications of "streaming" my data into the target file. Can I use the zlib compress() function in one process and then a master process with the flush() function to build the file? Does that ignore preceding data in the archive? Thanks much!

Comment: Lol [you're holding out on me](https://github.com/madler/pigz): "pigz was written by Mark Adler and does not include third-party code."

Comment: zlib's `compress()` doesn't write gzip streams, so no. You need to use a gzip compressor that works from memory to memory.

Comment: I feel like an ant being watched by God... How was Mars? :D Ok - I am trying to use gzip.compress(bytes(string, utf-8)) to get my data "chunk" into a binary format for writing with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') but it just comes back with "invalid compressed data--format violated" because, quite clearly, I have no idea what I'm doing. If you know of a particular library or gzip function that is exposed to python to allow for compression of the "string" or "stream" (I think "stream?") separately from the "write" component I would be most appreciative. Still searching!

Comment: Ok! `gzip.compress(bytes(string, utf-8),compresslevel=9)` being written to a plain old `open(filename,'wb')` seeeeeems like it's working. I have two processes compressing the data and then tossing it onto a queue that the writer uses. It can be opened by gzip and it even has the same file size as the original archive. Will confirm with larger data set and update question source code.

Comment: Tested it against a medium sized data set and it works *great*! Thank you for your time - I feel honored you'd spend any of it on me. And... without waxing eloquent... thank you for the contributions you've made to humanity! Truly incredible stuff you've done.

Comment: Mars is a frigid, barren, lifeless hellscape.

Comment: You really know how to sell it ;) Some day we'll all live there